# Best practice for Qt translations and git

Tags: git, qt, merge, localization, internationalization

Today I tried to merge two git branches of a Qt project.
Both branches had added some new strings and new translations for them.
Now Qt's lupdate tool stores the line number of the source file where the translation is needed in the .ts files.
As you can imagine the line numbers are not identical for two branches and when both translation files have been updated, this leads to hundreds of merge conflicts like this, for every single translation file:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
 +        <location filename="../../src/network/mail/CSmtp.cpp" line="856"/>
=======
+         <location filename="../../src/network/mail/CSmtp.cpp" line="860"/>
>>>>>>> master
```

You might say just use one of the versions and run lupdate again, but that way you lose all new translations from one of the branches.

Other tools, like gettext, don't not have this problem, since they do not store line numbers.

What are some good approaches to avoid this problem in Qt?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the `lupdate` man page:

> #### `-locations` {`absolute`|`relative`|`none`}
>
> Specify/override how source code references are saved in `ts` files.  Default is `absolute`.

So use **`lupdate -locations none`** to eliminate all line numbers in the TS files.  Use **`lupdate -locations relative`** to reduce the churn in line numbers: now, changes in line numbers will only affect the first string after each change, which might be an acceptable compromise if you use `linguist` with the source window open.

My preference is to commit to source-control just the version with `-locations none`.  Any time I need the line numbers, I run `lupdate` locally to generate a temporary version with absolute locations.  Make sure you don't commit the temporary!

Comment: Interesting to note that `lupdate` with _none_ will indeed delete the line numbers from existing TS files, but `lupdate` with line-numbers will not update the existing translations to add the context (I guess it would complete the new strings though).

Answer (score 5):

One possible solution (mentioned in [an answer to "Merge translation files (.ts) with existing .ts files"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8527556/6309)) is to use [`lconvert`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linguist-programmers.html).  When this was introduced, in Qt 4.5:

> The new `lconvert` filter tool facilitates conversion between file formats and can be used to perform other transformations on collections of translatable strings.

It involves a manual step (creating a second file with only the strings you want to merge), and then:

```
 lconvert -i primary.ts secondary.ts -o complete.ts
```

To complete the end result, [the answer to "Translation file still working after modifying the source?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18967576/6309) also mentions `pylupdate4 your_project.pro` as a way to update all the references to the lines in the `ts` file.

Answer (score 4):

You can drop the line numbers with `lupdate` too using `-locations none`. This will eliminate any conflicts with line numbers but you will lose the context of the strings in the sources. For `.ui` files there is also `-no-ui-lines` argument.

```
lupdate -locations none -no-ui-lines ...
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Check-in an empty TS that is valid XML, e.g. `./i18n/myapp_de.ts`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE TS>
   <TS version="2.1">
   </TS>
   ```
2. Run `lupdate -verbose -no-obsolete ./src-folder/ -ts ./i18n/myapp_de.ts` when sources changed.
3. Don't ask why this nicely creates new translation entries and proper contexts without line numbers while it doesn't if TS file does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you merge using the `ours` or `theirs` strategy (see [git merge doc](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) at the `MERGE STRATEGIES` chapter), you will have all the translations from both branches:

```
git merge branch1 -X theirs
git merge branch2 -X theirs
```

Then run the `lupdate` command to fix the rong number lines.